# How to know which links I have visited when making calls in parallel foreach?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, console-application

I am bulding a web-scraping project.

I have two lists:

```
    private ConcurrentQueue<string> links = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    private ConcurrentQueue<string> Visitedlinks = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
```

On for all the links that I find on a page and one which will hold all the links I have scraped.

Method that handels the business:

```
    public async Task GetUrlContent(string url)
    {
        var page = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            page = await service.Get(url);

            if (page != string.Empty)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"<a[^>]*?href\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>",
                    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

                if (regex.IsMatch(page))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Downloading url: " + url);
                    for (int i = 0; i < regex.Matches(page).Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value.StartsWith("/"))
                        {
                            if (!links.Contains(BaseUrl + regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value.ToLower().Replace(".html", "")) &&
                                !Visitedlinks.Contains(BaseUrl + regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value.ToLower()))
                            {
                                Uri ValidUri = GetUrl(regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value);
                                if (ValidUri != null && HostUrls.Contains(ValidUri.Host))
                                    links.Enqueue(regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value.ToLower().Replace(".html", ""));
                                else
                                 links.Enqueue(BaseUrl + regex.Matches(page)[i].Groups[1].Value.ToLower().Replace(".html", ""));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                var results = links.Where(m => !Visitedlinks.Contains(m)); // problkem here, get multiple values

                if (!results.Any())
                {
                    // do nothing
                }

                else
                {
                    Parallel.ForEach(results, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                            webpage =>
                            {
                                if (ValidUrl(webpage))
                                {
                                    if (!Visitedlinks.Contains(webpage))
                                    {
                                        Visitedlinks.Enqueue(webpage);
                                        GetUrlContent(webpage).Wait();
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Problem is here:

```
var results = links.Where(m => !Visitedlinks.Contains(m));
```

The first iteration I might get:

> Link1, link2, link3, link4,

Second iteration:

> Link2 link3 link4, link5, link6 ,link 7

Third:

> Link 3, link4, link 5, link 6, etc

This means that I will get the same links multiple times since this is a parallel foreach which does several operations at once. I can't figure out how to make sure that I dont get multiple values.

Anyone that can lend a helping hand?

Comment: why do you need `results`? just dequeue from `links`, and enqueue to `VisitedLinks` what you already harvested. The point of  a concurrent queue is that is [has a mechanism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208(v=vs.110).aspx) to ensure that multiple threads won't fetch the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the first queue contains the links you want to scrape, and the second queue contains the ones you have scraped.

The problem is that you're trying to iterate over the contents of your `ConcurrentQueue`:

```
var results = links.Where(m => !Visitedlinks.Contains(m));
```

This won't work predictably if you're accessing these queues from multiple threads.

What you should do is *take items out of the queue* and process them. What stands out is that `TryDequeue` doesn't appear anywhere in your code. Items are going into the queue but never coming out. The whole purpose of a queue is that we put things in and take them out. `ConcurrentQueue` makes it safe for multiple threads to put items in and take them out without stepping all over each other.

If you dequeue a link that you want to process:

```
string linkToProcess = null;
if(links.TryDequeue(out linkToProcess)) // if this returns false, the queue was empty
{
     // process it
}
```

Then as soon as you've taken an item out of the queue to process it, it won't be in the queue anymore. Other threads don't have to check to see if an item has been processed. They just take the next item out of the queue, if there is one. Two threads won't ever take the same item out of the queue. Only one thread can take a given item out of the queue, because as soon as it does, the item isn't in the queue anymore.

Comment: Not sure if I am implementing it right but when doing it this way it is nor parallel anymore, takes every link one by one and gets extremly slow

Comment: The parallel part comes in because you can have one process putting things in the queue while another takes them out. You could have multiple threads running at once to put things in the queue. Then one thread is reading from the queue, but you could start new threads to process individual items.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Scott Hannen

The final solution is as follows:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(links, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 25 },
            webpage =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (WebPageValidator.ValidUrl(webpage))
                    {
                        string linkToProcess = webpage;
                        if (links.TryDequeue(out linkToProcess) && !Visitedlinks.Contains(linkToProcess))
                        {
                            Task obj = Scrape(linkToProcess);
                            Visitedlinks.Enqueue(linkToProcess);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error("Error occured: " + e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error occured, check log for further details.");
                }
```